# Action after user login in Firebase Auth in Angular2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm using Firebase in my Angular2 app for user authentization.
It's working perfectly with one exception. After a user logs in I want to run a few methods to check if this is the first login for the user. I tried to turn the login into a promise, however `console.log(this.af.auth)` yields null as it seems to be called right after the user clicks the log in button but before the actual login is complete.

Any ideas how I can trigger an action after the user is logged in? In my case I want to check if the user already exist in my database and if not, create a new user.

```
 public login() {
    this.af.auth.login()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("user logged in");
        console.log(this.af.auth);
      });
  }
```

Comment: That code is completely fine, you might be doing something wrong, post the rest of the code, or try creating a plunker you might spot the problem while creating the plunker

Comment: Here are the settings

`const myFirebaseAuthConfig = {
  provider: AuthProviders.Google,
  method: AuthMethods.Redirect
};`

The issue seems to be that the `console.log(this.af.auth)` is called as the login button is clicked and thus returns null. However, I'm interesting in the state after the user has returned from the redirected site and has logged in using Google

Comment: Where did you get auth.login function? please take a look at the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth there are different sign in functions for each provider.

Comment: I'm using the official AngularFire2 docs: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md

Comment: You need to set up AngularFire2 in order for the parameterless `login()` call to work properly. Please show the [minimum *complete* code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that the issue was caused by an error that happened when the user was logged out. I have provided the plunker as suggested here: https://plnkr.co/edit/TNEL1mBh40ePH5ZDxOiS

I need to update my configuration to allow for states when the user is logged out and the getUserInformation() method won't have an auth provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is because you are using `this` keyword in callback function which has its own variable scope and it does not have `af.auth` property.

Try this.

```
public login() {
    var me = this;
    this.af.auth.login()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("user logged in");
        console.log(me.af.auth);
      });
}
```

#### UPDATE

Try to subscribe on `auth` object and you should be notified on auth state change.

```
this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
  if(auth) {
    console.log('logged in');
  } else {
    console.log('not logged in');
  }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it unfortunately. The "user logged in" is written to the console as soon as I click the login button, not when the user has completed the login and is redirected to my site

Comment: Which provider do you use?

Comment: I'm using Google login provider with the redirect setting:
`const myFirebaseAuthConfig = { provider: AuthProviders.Google, method: AuthMethods.Redirect }; The issue seems to be that the console.log(this.af.auth)`

Comment: Have you tried `AuthMethods.Popup`? What does it do? does it work as expected?

Comment: Thanks for that. The issue as mentioned above seems to be caused by an error in my code when the user was logged out